# Who is faster, Flashy Flash or Speed-o'-Sound Sonic?

Tags: one-punch-man

At some point in the webcomic, the speed of Flashy Flash's attack is given: it takes a centisecond to perform each attack. I suppose his speed can be calculated if you know the distance of his attacks. I don't know if Speed-o'-Sound Sonic's speed is given or it can be calculated, though it probably has to be over the speed of sound, right?

Who is faster, Flashy Flash or Speed of Speed-o'-Sound Sonic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](https://onepunchman.fandom.com/wiki/Speed-o%27-Sound_Sonic), which is also from the *One-Punch Man Encyclopedia*, it says that Speed-o'-Sound Sonic can enter *massively hypersonic speeds*. [Hypersonic speed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypersonic_speed) has a minimum of Mach 5 (1,715m/s). Meanwhile, Flashy Flash can perform 1 attack per 0.01s.

Not sure about my math but if we assume that each attack's distance is a meter long for Flashy Flash to achieve 0.01s, then Speed-o'-Sound Sonic can perform an attack at that same distance for approximately 0.00058309037s, given his speed is in Mach 5, which is the minimum for hypersonic speed.

This means that, based on approximation, **Speed-o'-Sound Sonic is much faster than Flashy Flash since it takes him less time to perform an attack**.

Comment: Odd how you request sources in the other answer and then make a large number of unsourced assumptions.  Which are all quite incorrect.  I count a panel where Flashy Flash makes about 14 melee attacks in no more than one ten-thousandth of a second, which makes your speed estimation off by several orders of magnitude.

Comment: Not to mention the apples to oranges comparison of movement speed versus attack speed.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy I only make do with the information given to me. The asker said that was an estimate from the webcomic so I used that information. My answer is based on what the question has given. Also, can you specify the 'unsourced assumptions'? Flashy Flash's speed was taken from the question. Speed o sonic speed is taken from the OPM encyclopedia. The Hypersonic speeds are estimate from wikipedia. If you think all the information is incorrect, then by all means, provide a better answer and references.

Comment: And link the chapter where you found the panel...

Comment: I had missed the part where he said that, so that explains that.  The op is mistaken.  It occurs in the span of 1/100-th of a centisecond, or one ten-thousandth of a second.  It's in Chapter 84 of the webcomic, pages 1-5.  It's not even the upper limit on his speed as he then starts going even faster, we're just not provided with the convenient stopwatch reading minutes : seconds' centiseconds" ten-thousandths when he starts going faster.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy I see. I assumed that was correct and did not bother to check, hence the off in estimation. Also, I overlooked the comparison on attack and move speed and assumed both were the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94441/discussion-between-zibadawa-timmy-and-w-are).

Answer (score 8):

While I do like Sonic much better, it's pretty obvious from what we've seen so far: (Manga Spoiler Alert)

1.Flashy and Sonic were from the same ninja village, same ninja class (44th "End Class" or whatever), same generation. Flashy was number 1 from this class.

2.The two ninja dudes (upper classmen from the same ninja school and village), that ate the monsterfication cells, were much faster than Sonic, while Flashy beat them pretty easy 1vs2.

Although Sonic is currently slower, I think that he will catch up at some point and maybe even surpass Flashy.

Comment: Please include relevant sources/references.

Comment: Regardless of the lack of sources, what he said at least in #2 is true. I don't remember where it's mentioned that Flashy Flash was number #1 from his class and that Sonic was from the same class or same generation

Answer (score 6):

The basis of your question is already kind of iffy.  Your ".01 second" figure is almost certainly based off the following page (and preceding ones) in Chapter 84 of the webcomic:

[image: many high speed attacks]

You can see something like 14 to 16 attacks were made in this picture, and the timer from the previous panel, before any attacks, was reading 00:00"00'01.

So the attacks happened in 00:00"00'01 units of time.  The question is, what units of time is that even using?  It doesn't say explicitly, and fans seem to fall into two camps.  Some seem to think the numbers before the : are hours, while others think it is minutes.  In the first case the span was 1 centisecond (=.01 s), while in the second
it is a hundredth of that: .0001s.

The first people are, in my estimation, a bunch of loons.  But to be fair there's actually reason to think it.  If you read a digital clock it'll use an hh:mm format, so that would naturally suggest the first unit in this image's stop watch is for hours.  Every (sprinter's) stopwatch I've ever seen, however, uses a mm:ss form, followed by centiseconds in some other format (usually just slightly smaller numbers). If you're measuring hours you're not measuring a sprinter, after all!  Going more precise than centiseconds is unusual for a stopwatch, as the inaccuracy in the human starting and stopping it is greater than that.  Professional sports timing devices (that aren't human-operated) and high-speed cameras can fairly easy achieve accuracy at the .0001s level, though many sports may find accuracy to .001s sufficient.

There are a few fans who have tried to estimate his movement speed and attack speed from the panels in this chapter.  The numbers kind of end up all over the place.  [This user used the .01s interval and calculated his hands during attacks moved at around Mach 5.3](https://vsbattles.fandom.com/wiki/User_blog:Gwynbleiddd/Lightspeed_flash_(calc)).  That's about the lower end of Speed of Sound sonic's (movement) speed suggested by W.Are's answer.  Using the .0001s interval you get Mach 530, instead, which is radically faster; 100 times faster.  I've seen a post saying the interval was a microsecond, which is .000001s, which gets us up around 1% to 2% of the speed of light.  But that definitely seems like a misreading of the stopwatch.

And one way or another, soon after this panel Flashy Flash starts moving even faster.  But we no longer have a stopwatch in the panels. However, he uses an after image technique much like we saw Sonic use against Saitama.  Sonic created 10 after images he was moving so fast.  But Flashy Flash moves so fast that the multitude of after images looks "like a snake":

> [image: chapter 84 page 07]

This indicates he is dramatically faster than Sonic, and attacks at upwards of Mach 5 (or Mach 500!)* when he's not even going full out.

---

<sub>*And that's making assumptions. Such as each fist going one at a time, and might underestimate the total distance each fist has to travel, as the previous one may twist the next one to attack further back. Just try a few boxing jabs and note how if you jab with your right then your body twists the right shoulder forward and the left back. You can also see in the image that there's apparently quite a lot of arc in the strikes, and even changes in attack angles suggesting he's moving a fair bit.  We're even making assumptions on the time interval: maybe everything up to before he started attacking left it just short of hitting the 02 number, and in that tiny span left he finished every attack exactly as the time hit 02.  We just don't have enough digits of precision to be sure; but traditional storytelling norms suggest our assumption is accurate.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

In the more recent chapters of the one punch man webcomic sonic and flash meet up for a duel and sonic forces flash to use one of his ultimate techniques flash kick and sonic actually dodges it and he dodges it fairly easily and is unfazed by flash he even states that he could kill flash even i think sonic might be faster then flash

Comment: These two are massive braggarts so it's unwise to take statements from them like "I can kill you myself" as true until they've actually done so.  Also whether he dodged it easily is up to interpretation: his cheek is shown singed and smoking afterwards.  Still, yes, if the fight resumes being 1v1 we might get a definitive answer on who wins in a fight.  But best we can say for now is that Flashy Flash is very surprised at how good Sonic is.